# How do I access histogram data from Python?

Tags: python, rendering

I am trying to adjust the rendered image exposure using the histogram in the compositor, and I would like to automate it. But, how can I get the data from the graph in the image below?

[image: Histogram graph view]

Comment: Maybe not yet possible https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/nOLW/?sorting=hot

Comment: What is so weird is that I see references to it in the Python API, but with no clear way of how to get the data...
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scopes.html#bpy.types.Scopes.histogram
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Histogram.html#bpy.types.Histogram

Comment: I've seen that too. But as you say, the exposed properties are very limited.

Comment: Though, I did get this in the Python console...
"No reference available 'Histogram.mode', Update info in 'rna_manual_reference.py' or callback to bpy.utils.manual_map()"

Comment: AFAIK this just lets you create the UI, you don't actually access the data. If you RMB > Edit source, you can see how this is used.